# I can't understand "min" in this equation

Tags: terminology

[image: can't understand min/a,b]

The above equation is from this paper:

http://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci1290/results/final/valayshah/Matting-Levin-Lischinski-Weiss-CVPR06.pdf

It has a min/a,b , which I don't understand. It is not the argmin, right?

Comment: It means take the $\min$ over all values of $a,b$.

Comment: This means that $J(\alpha)$ is is the minimum value obtained of the expression $J(\alpha,a,b)$ after plugging in all values of $a$ and $b$ possible.

Comment: It is the minimal value of $J(\alpha, a, b)$ where $\alpha$ is chosen beforehand and then we look at the values for all pairs $(a,b)$ and pick the minimal value